# How/where can I register a new type for querying within ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

When querying, ActiveRecord automagically decides how to handle ranges, arrays, etc. based on column type.

Now what I want to do is query an integer column for a set of bit values by calling something like `Model.where(bitfield: [1,4,16,32]).count` where it will build a query accordingly, counting all objects that have at least one of those bits set.

I already know how to build the resulting SQL, I'm looking for a place to put my code that will basically check for the column type, find out I configured it to be `bitfield` and use my handler to build the relevant SQL parts.

Comment: Hey, not sure to understand well but you can create your own Integer type by overriding ActiveRecord::Type::Integer methods in a Bitfield model. Then you can set each attributes type in your models like so : `attribute :int_var, Bitfield.new`. For the custom query, I dont know how to do it :).

Comment: Ah, this is a good pointer. Maybe I can find the query logic somewhere down the type route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to make a `bit_where` method in your model which is bitfield-aware...

```
class Model << ActiveRecord::Base

  BITFIELDS = [:bitfield]

  def self.bit_where(*args, options={})
  bitfield_options = {}
  options.each do |k, v|
    if BITFIELDS.include?(k)
      bitfield_options[k] = v
      options.delete(k)
    end
  end
  collection = self.where(*args, options) # the regular "where" query
  bitfield_options.each do |k, v|
    ... collection.where( custom sql here based on each key, value )
  end
  collection
end
```

Comment: This is what I'll probably resort to, yes. Still hoping to find a hidden pluggable structure to exploint.

Comment: You can add the method to a concern in models/concerns and then include the concern in all models that need it.